# cancelAllLocalNotifications is not working in iOS 8/ 9

Tags: swift

Put simply

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

doesn't clear all remote notifications in notification center. I'm not using app badge notifications so I'm not worried about that. I ran it on both iOS8 and iOS9 and doesn't work...no idea why.

Comment: If I understand "clear all remote notifications in notification center" correctly (removing the notifications from notification center), then `cancelAllLocalNotifications` doesn't do that. It only cancels notifications that haven't been sent yet.

Comment: This method won't clear remote notification in notification center. This method is for Localnotifications only not for remote notification.

Comment: @TroyT so then how do you cancel all remote notifications? My database is with Parse

Comment: I don't really have Parse knowledge, but checking out the Parse documentation would probably be a good idea.